# Discord.js -- conditional statement

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a code that asks you a question, then you answer so like a staff app bot, So when the bot asks a question, you must answer within the time given, and I want the response to be numbers only. So here is my current code:

```
   message.author.send(questions.firstQuestion).then(msg => {
            const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
            msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                time: 5 * 60000,
                max: 1
            }).then(messages => {
                let msg1 = messages.first().content
                let mas2 = parseInt(messages.first().content)
                if(msg1.toLowerCase() === "cancel") {
                message.author.send("Ok, I have cancelled this process")
                } else if(msg1.toLowerCase() === "programmer") { message.author.send('Succesfully worked')}
                else if(msg1.toLowerCase() === "editor") { 
                
               
                
                message.author.send('how much robux?').then(msg => {
                   if (isNaN(mas2)) {
                        message.author.send('Not a number!');
                     }
                 // message.author.send(questions.secondQuestion).then(msg => {
                    const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                    msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                        time: 5 * 60000,
                        max: 1
                    
                    }).then(messages => {
                        let msg2 = messages.first().content
                        if(msg2.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("Ok, I have cancelled this process")
                        message.author.send(questions.thirdQuestion).then(msg => {
                            const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                            msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                                time: 5 * 60000,
                                max: 1
                            }).then(messages => {
                                let msg3 = messages.first().content
                                if(msg3.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("Ok, I have cancelled this process")
                                message.author.send(questions.fourthQuestion).then(msg => {
                                    const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                                    msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                                        time: 5 * 60000,
                                        max: 1
                                    }).then(messages => {
```

But even if I say a letter, it doesn't say this is not a number, how to fix?

Comment: `if(typeof message === "number") // do number stuff`

Comment: What is `mas2` defined as?

Comment: @Elitezen  let mas2 = parseInt(messages.first().content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `mas2` evaluates to `Message#content`, you can simply call `isNaN()` with the string.

`isNaN()` will return `true` if the given input **is** **N**ot **a** **N**umber

```
if (isNaN(mas2)) {
   message.author.send('Not a number!');
}
```

[MDN Documentation on isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Comment: Here's my new code, and doesn't seem to work

Comment: You've checkmarked my answer, are you still having trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `isNaN` method. If the string is not a number, it returns true, if it is a number, it returns false

```js
isNaN(2) //false
isNaN('2') //false
isNaN('2a') //true
isNaN(2e7) //false
isNaN('some random string') //true

//TESTING WITH MESSAGE CONTENT

//say the message content is 1000
isNaN(message.content) //false
//but if it was something like 'haha'
isNaN(message.content) //true
```

Comment: Please say what you don’t understand instead of just saying 'What????'

Comment: That literally has nothing to do with my problem

Comment: You said you wanted the response to be numbers only?

Comment: Yes so let me explain it clearly, the bot ask question, I want the response of the user to be number only, he cant answer the next question if he can't answer it correctly, and the answer must only be a number

Comment: I literally answered exactly that

Comment: You want to check if the string is a number, correct?

Comment: Try it in a web browser console. Test it out with `isNaN(3)` and `isNaN('random string')` and even `isNaN('3')`

Comment: I tried that in my code, doesn't seem to work, pastebin.com/hEryyXQk

Comment: Where exactly in your code? I tried to look for it.

Comment: Here's my full code - https://pastebin.com/vKJXxqNi

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the part you added `isNaN` to?

Comment: I edited my question, you can see it now.

Comment: I still don’t see where you used `isNaN`

Comment: There I fixed it.

Comment: It could be the duplicate `messages` variable. You declared that too many times, and you should make it a different name every time so you don’t get complications

Comment: the messages variable works just fine tho, I just wanna add something and it doesn't work.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of

```
                 if(mas2 > 1) {
                message.author.send('Not a number!')
```

You can use

```
if(!typeof var !== number)
{return message.reply('Not a number!'}
```

Replace var with the variable you are checking or the argument

Comment: Why are you using `!` on `typeof`? Also `var` is a reserved keyword, that code on it's own will throw an error

Comment: Also you are missing a `)` at the end of `Message#reply()`